# Designating columns based on element order in XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

My XML is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<JobListing>
    <ColumnOrder>
        <columnId>4</columnId>
        <columnId>2</columnId>
        <columnId>5</columnId>
        <columnId>1</columnId>
        <columnId>3</columnId>
    </ColumnOrder>
    <Jobs>
        <Job>
            <title>Java Developer</title>
            <code>JAVA</code>
            <openings>10</openings>
            <location>USA</location>
            <duration>6 months</duration>
        </Job>
        <Job>
            <title>.NET Developer</title>
            <code>DOTNET</code>
            <openings>10</openings>
            <location>USA</location>
            <duration>6 months</duration>
        </Job>
    </Jobs>
</JobListing>
```

I've a specific requirement that Jobs should be listed in a HTML page based on `ColumnOrder` specified  in the XML. Internally, each `columnId` is mapped to a column as given below:

- 1 -> Title
- 2 -> Code
- 3 -> Openings
- 4 -> Location
- 5 -> Duration

In this case, for example, Job listing page should list columns in this order - `Location, Code, Duration, Title, Openings`.  Am expecting something like as explained below:

```
<tr>
  loop jobs
     for each columnorder
              if(columnId == 1)
                        <td>get Title</td>
              else if (columnId == 2)
                        <td>get Code</td>
              else if (columnId == 3)
                        <td>get Openings</td>
              else if (columnId == 4)
                        <td>get Location</td>
              else if (columnId == 5)
                        <td>get Duration</td>
              end if
     end columnorder
  end jobs
</tr>
```

How do I achieve this using XSLT?

Any help or different ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** The `<Job>` elements in the XML (title, openings, location, duration, code) are not necessarily in the same order. In fact, in our current framework, it gets generated in ascending order (like code, duration, location, openings, title).  How to make it work without taking into account order of elements of `<Job>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation works even when the children of `Job` are mixed in any order**:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <my:Mapping>
       <id val="1">title</id>
       <id val="2">code</id>
       <id val="3">openings</id>
       <id val="4">location</id>
       <id val="5">duration</id>
     </my:Mapping>

     <xsl:variable name="vOrder" select="/*/ColumnOrder/*"/>

     <xsl:variable name="vMap" select=
          "document('')/*/my:Mapping/*"/>

     <xsl:template match="Jobs">
         <table>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </table>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="Job">
      <tr>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
         <xsl:sort data-type="number" select=
          "count($vOrder
                      [. = $vMap
                              [. = name(current())]/@val
                      ]
                       /preceding-sibling::*
                 )
          "/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
      </tr>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="Job/*">
      <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="ColumnOrder"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<JobListing>
    <ColumnOrder>
        <columnId>4</columnId>
        <columnId>2</columnId>
        <columnId>5</columnId>
        <columnId>1</columnId>
        <columnId>3</columnId>
    </ColumnOrder>
    <Jobs>
        <Job>
            <title>Java Developer</title>
            <code>JAVA</code>
            <openings>10</openings>
            <location>USA</location>
            <duration>6 months</duration>
        </Job>
        <Job>
            <title>.NET Developer</title>
            <code>DOTNET</code>
            <openings>10</openings>
            <location>USA</location>
            <duration>6 months</duration>
        </Job>
    </Jobs>
</JobListing>
```

**The wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>USA</td>
      <td>JAVA</td>
      <td>6 months</td>
      <td>Java Developer</td>
      <td>10</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>USA</td>
      <td>DOTNET</td>
      <td>6 months</td>
      <td>.NET Developer</td>
      <td>10</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Gnanam: My solution has other advantages, too. Despite being more generic, it at the same time is quite simpler -- there are no explicit conditional instructions (no `xsl:choose` or `xsl:when`. The embedded XML can be passed as a parameter, and this is in sharp contrast with Mads' solution where values are hardcoded. It is you who decide. If you were to accept Mads' answer I wouldn't be mad at you -- it is better when you have good answers to accept one rather than not accepting any. If you feel so remorseful about not accepting mine, you can compensate in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="JobListing">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Jobs">
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Job">
        <tr>
            <xsl:variable name="currentJob" select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each select="/JobListing/ColumnOrder/columnId">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current()=1">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentJob/title" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="current()=2">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentJob/code" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="current()=3">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentJob/openings" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="current()=4">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentJob/location" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="current()=5">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentJob/duration" />
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Job/*">
        <td>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </td>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--Don't render ColumnOrder-->
    <xsl:template match="ColumnOrder"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the sample input produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>USA</td>
        <td>JAVA</td>
        <td>6 months</td>
        <td>Java Developer</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>USA</td>
        <td>DOTNET</td>
        <td>6 months</td>
        <td>.NET Developer</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks.  It is working as given above.  But, it is my small mistake I've *not clearly* explained one thing in the question.  The `<Job>` elements in the XML (title, openings, location, duration, code) are not necessarily in the same order.  In fact, in our current framework, it gets generated in ascending order.  How do I make it work in that case?

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I didn't pay close enough attention when reading your question.  Updated answer.

Comment: But from your updated answer, the columns are not changing/working.  Whatever order I change in XML, it is always listing in the order as it is written in XSL.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ah!, yes, I found.  I have to remove this `<xsl:sort select="."/>`.  Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, removing the sort will give you the output matching the `columnId` in document order.  I've updated the answer to remove sort.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Job"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Job">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../../ColumnOrder/columnId">
                <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="position()"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="columnId">
        <xsl:param name="pos"/>

        <xsl:copy-of select="../../Jobs/Job[position() = $pos]/*[position() = current()/.]"/>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Job>
  <location>USA</location>
  <code>JAVA</code>
  <duration>6 months</duration>
  <title>Java Developer</title>
  <openings>10</openings>
</Job>
<Job>
  <location>USA</location>
  <code>DOTNET</code>
  <duration>6 months</duration>
  <title>.NET Developer</title>
  <openings>10</openings>
</Job>
```